# Regular Expression Matching Repeating Patterns

Tags: regex

I'm trying to develop regular expressions to check syntax for question writing for a quiz module.

One question type is drag and drop which has the format ...

`the {rain} falls gently on the {plain}`

... where the bracketed terms are draggable. There has to be at least one bracketed term but they can come anywhere in the string. The doesn't need to be anything between the bracketed terms either. So any of the following are valid ...

`{the} rain falls gently on the plain`

`the rain falls gently on the {plain}`

`{the} {rain} {falls} {gently} {on} {the} {plain}`

`{the }{rain }{falls }{gently }{on }{the }{plain}`

Also, to complicate matters, there can't be any square brackets inside the braces - this is another question type. So ...

`{the} {rain}`

... is OK, but ...

`{the} {[rain]}`

... is not and any other combination.

So far, I've got this but it clearly doesn't work :(

`(.*\{.*\})+`

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: This may do the trick https://regex101.com/r/k2BTpu/2

Comment: Can there be `{` and `}` between the `{}`?

Comment: Yes it very well can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `{` and `}` can not occur between the `{}` and the square brackets can be present outside of the curly braces but not inside, you might use:

```
^[^\r\n{}]*(?:{[^\][\r\n{}]*}[^\r\n{}]*)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\r\n{}]*` Repeat 0+ times any char except a newline or `{` and `}`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `{[^\][\r\n{}]*}` Match `{`, then 0+ times any char except a newline or any of `[]{}`
  - `[^\r\n{}]*` Match 0+ times any following chars except a newline or `{` and `}`
- `)+` Close group and repeat at least 1 or more times to make sure there is a draggable `{...}`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RbsVHq/1)

Comment: Yep - thank you - that seems to work perfectly. I shall study it and learn more :)

Comment: After studying this a little, do you never need to specify "any character" as a dot at any point in this? So is matching any character explicit in RegEx? Sorry for not getting this :(

Comment: It is not mandatory to use a dot to write a pattern. In this pattern the negated character classes specify what you want to allow to match except what is listed.

Comment: Right - so this could be the issue with this - I can't get the string to match without the .+ being present but then it matches everything after it, even if the syntax is wrong.

https://regex101.com/r/oHz9P8/1

I guess I need to use capturing groups?

The correct syntax must be ...

`{[answer][yes]}{[answer][no]}{[answer][no]}{[answer][no]}`

There can only be one 'yes' and as many 'no' as required (there is no limit on options in the question) and the 'yes' and 'no's can be anywhere in the string.

Phew - this is harder than I thought.

Comment: @MrMills The `.+` is a very broad match and will match until the end of the string first and will then backtrack trying to fit the rest of the pattern. You might do it like this by repeating the no patterns and match at least a single yes pattern https://regex101.com/r/JKJiYb/1

Comment: OK, I see - you've included 'answer' in the regex but this can be literally anything (sorry might not have made that clear). How do I change it so that there has to be at least one character in the first set of square brackets within each brace pair?

Comment: @MrMills You could use a negated character class matching any char except `[` or `]` and repeat that 1+ times for at least a single char. https://regex101.com/r/vso2tE/1

Comment: @MrMills You are not repeating the character classes using a quantifier like `+`  If you don't repeat it, you will match only a single char, see https://regex101.com/r/611nMy/1

Comment: Yeah! Beautiful! Is there a reason why the groups are non-capturing? Does this literally just avoid the processing overhead of matching the individual groups - for instance ... https://regex101.com/r/tGnX0K/4 ... only returns match on the full string?